# Что является грамматической основой главной части спп "Ничего удивительного, что тут же сидят лягушки"?

Tags: синтаксис

Что является грамматической основой главной части предложения
*"Ничего удивительного, что тут же сидят лягушки"?*

Answer (score 1):

Грамматическая основа безличного предложения -отрицательная  конструкция - фразеологизм "ничего удивительного"с пропуском слова НЕТ.